# Change image of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses the UITableViewCellStyleDefault style. I also have set the detail accessory:

```
    cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

I want the code to be so that when the detail accessory is push, thus generating the delegate method accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: , the image of that particular cell is changed to another image.

How can I do that? Do I need to recreate the cell somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no you have to just add the other image in the cell's imageview as

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGENAME"];
```

Comment: That's short and sweet! cellForRowAtIndexPath does the trick! Thanks a lot Aalok.

Comment: Note that, while this works, for "larger" cells this produces a lot of overhead, because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dequeues and reconfigures the whole cell (you did implement the method yourself didnt you? So you know what happens in there). Also, you'll later run into consistency problems, because your cells don't match your data structure anymore (i.e. image changes when you call reloadData). However, for small/testing purposes, this is fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Now You have your sekected cell, you can set the image which you have set on this cell
    UIImageView  *aView = (UIImageView*)[aCell viewWithTag:1];
    // Now change the image of aView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method use --

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView.delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

i've never done that but id try something like

```
-accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath..{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // change the view of cell here
}
```

just an idea, please add some code of what you've tried so far in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You change the image of your underlying data structure. After that, reload the cell at the appropiate index path.

For example, I assume your data is a simple NSArray with NSDictionary objects in it. The dictionary contains a few keys, like "text" and "image". In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would use the values in the appropiate dictionary to set cell.text and cell.image.

So, in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` (or maybe you want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?), you would do something like that:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[dict setValueForKey:@"image":myNewImage];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Bear in mind that's pseudo-code, not tested, but will give you the idea how to do it.